# Laravel NPM error "npm run watch " in command line

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm

i am new in Laravel and npm,
When i try to run "npm run watch" in command line of my Laravel proyect i got this

*NPM error  mix.js() is missing required parameter 1: entry   at Function.js*

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-01-29T04_31_51_161Z-debug.log

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch: `npm run development -- --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR!
This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-01-29T04_31_51_240Z-debug.log*

i do not know what is this and how to solve it, any help in how to solve this?
thank you very much in advance and support

Comment: what is your node versions ?  `node -v` you can check by

Comment: when i apply in command line "node -v" it appears v10.19.0

Comment: update that https://nodejs.org/en/ then run all cmd

Comment: After update nodejs to v15.7.0 and npm to 7.4.3 and type in command line "npm run watch" i got this message AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: mix.js() is missing required parameter 1: entry npm ERR! code 1
pm ERR! command sh -c cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"

Comment: when did you get that error? Did you change your webpack.mix.js file?

Comment: i just changed webpack.mix.js archive with another  webpack.mix.js archive of a  proyect that previosly npm "works fine" and it works!!! I don't know what did happen with this webpack.mix.jx,maybe it was corrupt, thank you very much for your support my problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's `mix.js()` takes at least one parameter. In the project root directory look at webpack.mix.js file, and then check mix.js().

For example `mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/assets/js/generated');`

For more information you can visit [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix).

Comment: Thank you, i already solved my problem, changing webpack.mix.jx, i guess it was corrupt  i changed this archive with another webpack.mx.jx arrchive that was correct, thank you very much